# Usando Libreria Quartz con aplicación Net 5.0, local se inicia sin inconveniente la tarea pero al realizar el despliegue en el servidor no funciona

Tags: .net-5, quartz

Estoy trabajando con la libreria quartz para el manejo de ejecución de tareas en segundo plano, mi aplicación esta en .Net 5.0.

Localmente al ejecutar la aplicación, la ejecución de las tareas funciona sin inconvenientes.
El tema se presenta al realizar el despliegue al servidor windowsserver2016, ahí ya no funciona, simplemente no se inicia la tarea.

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo, si es algo de configuración en el servidor.

Gracias

Comment: Algo en los logs?

Comment: No sr, precisamente coloque varios logs para tratar de capturar error si se está presentando pero nada. Es como si simplemente no detectará, no reconociera la libreria.

Comment: Está difícil que haya respuestas útiles. No hay archivos de configuración o algo que permita conocer el contexto; no hay ningún log de error. En el visor de eventos de windows no hay nada relacionado?